# How to solve the following system : $ \begin{cases} 2x^2 +x + z = 0 \\ (1-z) x^2 + 3x - y = 0 \\ (2+y) x^2 + 4x - 2 = 0 \end{cases} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Is there an algebraic method to solve the following system in $ \mathbb{C} $,

$$ \begin{cases} 2x^2 +x + z = 0 \\ (1-z) x^2 + 3x - y = 0 \\ (2+y) x^2 + 4x - 2 = 0 \end{cases} $$ ?.

Here, $ y \not \in \{ 0, -2 \} $, and $ z \not \in \{ 0,1 \} $.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Show please your attempts and I'll show my solution.

Comment: I made the system in the following form, $ \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & z \\ 1-z & 3 & -y \\ 2+y & 4 & -2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x^2 \\ x \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $, but, it doesn't work.

Comment: We need to solve $2x^6+x^5+x^4+3x^3+2x^2+4x-2=0,$ which is something strange. Maybe check the given...

Answer (score 0):

Hijacking the concept behind Michael Rozenberg's comment, the first thing to do is check that you copied the problem correctly.

Assuming so, 
let $f(x) = -(2x^2 + x)$ 
and let $g(x) = [1 - f(x)]x^2 + 3x.$

From the first equation, $z = f(x)$, so 
the 2nd equation gives $y = g(x).$

Thus, the 3rd equation becomes 
$[2 + g(x)]x^2 + 4x - 2 = 0.$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \begin{cases} 2x^2 +x + z = 0 \\ (1-z) x^2 + 3x - y = 0 \\ (2+y) x^2 + 4x - 2 = 0 \end{cases} $$

subtract equation 1 from 3 :

$$yx^2+3x-z=0$$

Make a system with equation 2:

$$ \begin{cases} yx^2+3x-z=0 \\ (1-z) x^2 + 3x - y = 0 \end{cases} $$

ُThe value of x from both equations must be equal, so we must have:

$x=\frac {3 ± \sqrt{9+4yz}}y=\frac{3 ±\sqrt{9+4y(1-z)}}{1-z}$

Now we may assume that:

$3 ±\sqrt{9+4yz}= 3 ±\sqrt{9+4y(1-z)}$ ⇒ $yz=y(1-z)$

$y=1-z$

Now solve following system and find y and z. Plugging z in first equation will give you two roots for x.

$$ \begin{cases} y(1-z)=yz\\ y=1-z  \end{cases} $$

Comment: I have trouble following your logic.  After the two equations that follow
"Make a system with equation 2:", shouldn't the next equations be 
$x = \frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{9 + 4yz}}{2y}  = \frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{9 + 4y(1-z)}}{2(1-z)}$?
I can't examine your answer further until this question is resolved.

Comment: @user2661923, you are right. I edited my answer.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the discrepancies re my previous comment still persist.  Further, even without those discrepancies, your subsequent logic of "Now we may assume that ..." seems to use the idea that if $\frac{A}{B} = \frac{C}{D},$ then we can assume that $A = C.$  I am also having trouble following that logic, but first things first.  As I said, it looks like the discrepancy re my previous comment persists.